# WinMerge : how to ignore specific words in a comparison?

Tags: winmerge

When I compare 2 files with WinMerge on Windows platform, do you know how could I ignore specific words ?

I mean I wanna say to WinMerge : "Don't care about that list of words : house, garden, etc."

An so when comparing those 2 lines :

```
the house is at london
```

&

```
the bus is at london
```

then **no difference** will be displayed since I don't care about the word house...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

In winmerge 2.16 (at least) (2020-05), you can use menu Plugins > Plugin Settings...

Click on PrediffLineFilter.sct, then click on the "Plugin Settings..." button, check in "Use RegExp" check box in the corresponding column. In the "Find what" column, specify a regexp and leave the "Replace with" cell empty. Close this plugin configuration window. Then, in the Plugins > Prediffer menu, select PrediffLineFilter.sct.

You can then turn off this filter plugin using menu Plugins > Prediffer > No Prediffer (normal).

Comment: This one works for me. One thing though, when comparing folders, it seems that the Prediffer is not applied to the files. How can I apply the prediffer when comparing folders?

Answer (score 2):

I know its been a while since this was asked, but since this shows up as a top match when searching for this topic, I thought I'd add to it...

As far as I can tell, WinMerge STILL doesn't have this functionality directly.  You have 2 options:
1) Write your own plugin for WinMerge.  It does seem to be possible to do what you want that way if you wish to invest the time.
2) Get [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/).  It includes the ability to use regex to [ignore the parts of a line](http://meldmerge.org/help/text-filters.html) you don't want compared.  For example, if you just put "word" in the text filter preferences it will ignore "word" and compare all other parts of the line.  I use this to compare dmesg logs in Linux, ignoring the timer field at the start with "^[.*?]" (ignore everything between the initial brackets, non-greedy).

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the moment for something similar, so perhaps this may be helpful for you:

WinMerge does not allow to filter parts of a line. If a line filter matches, the whole line is ignored. See http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html for an explanation of line filters.

So if there is a difference other than the word bus and house in it, the line will be ignored as well.