# How to apply a prediffer to WinMerge such that it runs on all files in the diff?

Tags: winmerge

**TL;DR: How can I automatically apply PrediffLineFilter on all diff results, not manually on only the open file?**

WinMerge 2.16.4.0 supports using plugin prediffers to, among things, diff while ignoring items that meet conditions specified with a regular expression*. However it appears you must manually apply the prediff after you perform the diff (huh?) and on each and every individual file if it doesn't match a file filter. The help manual indicates the file filter for PrediffLineFilter.sct is *.txt and gives no guide to changing it.

I have thousands of files where the only difference might be a server name which follows a predictable pattern. (Example: server01, server02, etc.) I have figured out the regex for that pattern and the manual application of PrediffLineFilter after a diff works. But I can't be doing that on thousands of files.

How can I automatically apply PrediffLineFilter on all diff results, not manually on only the open file? I only want to see the files where the differences are meaningful.

*Learned this thanks to [WinMerge : how to ignore specific words in a comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469870/winmerge-how-to-ignore-specific-words-in-a-comparison/61884911#61884911)

Comment: I am having this issue too. It works on files with only a few lines but doesn't work on files with about 100 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your winmerge installation folder, go to MergePlugins then edit the PrediffLineFilter.sct. Then change the return of get_PluginFileFilters to files you want this plugin to work on. For example you want this plugin to work on html and txt files:

```
Function get_PluginFileFilters()
    get_PluginFileFilters = "\.html$;\.txt$"
End Function
```

After you have made these changes, select all the files on your folder compare window then right click > Plugin Settings > Prediffer Settings >  Auto Prediffer, then refresh.
Btw, in the later versions(2.16.10) you can do this in the Plugin Settings window.

[image]

Comment: To get it working, I had one more step: enabling Plugins > Automatic Prediffer. After this, files that matched my filemask of \.xml$;\.config$ and containing text that matched my regexex in Plugins > Plugin Settings... > PrediffLineFilter.sct > Plugin Settings were correctly treated as identical. (A reminder/warning that if the regex matches even a single word in the line, the whole line is ignored - that's just how line filters work as per the very top of https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Filters.html.) Thank you!